# How to customise calendar week view's day title?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

[image]

For example, how can I show  `Jul 4 (Mon)` instead of the default `Mon` as day title?

Answer (score 2):

Y rectify like this and that seems good for me:

```
function template_preprocess_calendar_week(&$vars) {
$min_date = clone $vars['view']->date_info->min_date;
foreach ($vars['day_names'] as &$cell) {
 $cell['date'] = $min_date->format('j');
 $cell['data'] = $cell['data'] . ", " . $cell['date'];
 $min_date = $min_date->modify('+1 day');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your own theme template for your calendar month display.

Within the Views UI under the **Advanced > Theme: Information** link you'll find a link to display the template for **calendar-month.tpl.php**. You can copy the template over to your theme's template directory. After flush the cache, you can start using that copy as your own custom calendar month template.

Within the template you can see where the header is added via iteration over the `$day_names` variable.

```
<div class="calendar-calendar"><div class="month-view">
<table class="full">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <?php foreach ($day_names as $id => $cell): ?>
        <th class="<?php print $cell['class']; ?>" id="<?php print $cell['header_id'] ?>">
          !!!<?php print $cell['data']; ?>
        </th>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can alter it accordingly.

Alternatively, if you prefer to just alter the templates variables. You can add your own theme function for [`template_preprocess_calendar_month()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21calendar%21theme%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_calendar_month/7) in your theme's **template.php**. For example:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_calendar_month(&$vars) {
  // @TODO: Alter $vars['day_names'] to adjust day headers
}
```

Comment: I traced to `function calendar_week_header($view) ` in calendar.module and found the title text are built from `calendar_untranslated_days` which contains only weekday names (i.e. "Mon", "Tue", .. etc.), it seems the actual day info (e.g. 4th) is not there.

Comment: Your need (adding a day context) is different from the template's design (a generic label that describes each day in the column). You'll need to add your own logic to determine the day context.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Shawn Conn's tips, here is how I modify the `$day_names`:

```
function template_preprocess_calendar_week(&$vars) {

  ...

  $min_date = clone $vars['view']->date_info->min_date;
  foreach ($day_names as &$cell) {
    $cell['date'] = $min_date->format('M j');
    $cell['data'] = $cell['data'] . ", " . $cell['date'];
    $min_date = $min_date->modify('+1 day');
  }

  ...
}
```